# Enable getUserMedia using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webcam, getusermedia

I'm using the WebCodeCam (https://github.com/andrastoth/WebCodeCam) script for scanning QR-Codes using the camera of my tablet. The problem is that I'm getting an error message saying that my browser is not supporting getUserMedia when it does work on my laptop that is also using chrome.

I'm looking for a solution that automatically (or after confirmation message for the user) enables the getUserMedia using javascript/jQuery.

I found an article about chrome://flags and how to enable the necessary flags but the chrome://flags page only shows 2 flags on my tablet that are unrelated.
If the right flags were showing I could be able to run command line code using javascript to enable the flags but this is not the case.

Comment: What kind of device and version of OS are you running? Currently a very small number of mobile devices support getUserMedia

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found out that getUserMedia (like xdumaine mentionted) is not very supported by a lot of mobile devices. For me it worked on all android devices but not on iOS (not even with chrome).

Supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream